# Determine whether $f$ is continuous or discontinuous from the right or left at $x_0=0$ of $f(x)= 1$ if $x=0$, $ x \sin \frac{1}{x}$, otherwise

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine whether $f$ is continuous or discontinuous from the right or left at $x_0=0$, given:
>   $$f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1, & x=0\\
> x \sin\frac{1}{x}, &  x \neq 0
> \end{cases}$$

from the left: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} x \sin \frac{1}{x}=0 \neq f(0) =1$

from the right: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x \sin \frac{1}{x}=0 \neq f(0) =1$

It follows, by definition, that $f$ is discontinuous from the right or left at $x_0=0$

Is my argumentation correct? sufficient? Much appreciated

Comment: You can apply the squeeze theorem to find the limits.  And since $f(0)\ne\lim_\limits{x\to 0} f(x)$ then the function is not continuous.

Comment: Your argument is fine.  But the limit exists, so no need to evaluate the right and left sided limits separately.

Comment: You wrote “from the right or left”, but what you did proves that $f$ is discontinuous from right *and* left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that The value of x can take a maximum of 1 and a minimum of negative one!

$$-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$$

So the same applies to

$$-1 \leq \sin \frac{1}{x} \leq 1$$

Now let's multiply the inequality with $x$,

$$-x \leq x\sin \frac{1}{x} \leq x$$

Taking the limit for all three quantities!

$$\lim_{\text x \rightarrow 0}-x \leq \lim_{\text x \rightarrow 0} x\sin \frac{1}{x} \leq \lim_{\text x \rightarrow 0} x $$

Know that

$$\lim_{\text x \rightarrow 0}-x =0 $$

$$\lim_{\text x \rightarrow 0} x=0$$

So limit for $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ is

$$\lim_{\text x \rightarrow 0} x\sin \frac{1}{x}=0$$

Now let's check if the function is continuous

By definition of continuity we must have

$$\lim_{\text x \rightarrow 0} x\sin \frac{1}{x}= f(0)$$

Obviously the above is false since

$$\lim_{\text x \rightarrow 0} x\sin \frac{1}{x}=0 \neq f(0)=1$$

Addendum

The squeeze theorem sates as follows for the function exists on interval $[a,b]$
There exists a value c such that

$$a(x) \leq b(x) \leq c(x) $$

$$\lim_{\text x \rightarrow c}a(x) =L $$

$$\lim_{\text x \rightarrow c}c(x)= L$$

We can conclude that

$$\lim_{\text x \rightarrow c}b(x) =L $$